# JavaFx in standard jre

Tags: java, javafx

I want to use XCalendarPicker written on javaFX from jfxtras.org in my swing project. But I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/runtime/FXObject
```

Must I to install javaFx runtime, or there is way no to do so?

Comment: @deporter, ok, but when i use, for example, javafx.scene.control.Label, it work fine without javafx runtime. But I need XCalendarPicker and it don't work

Comment: i don't know but xcalendarpicker may be in latest javafx 2.0, if you have installed an older javafx (1.3) you might get error, that's normal.

Comment: @deporter, I didn't install javafx runtime, I use library jfxrt.jar from javafx_sdk-2_0_3, and XCalendarPicker is written in javafx 1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use JavaFX 1.3 code with JavaFX 2.0 library. It's not possible. JavaFX 1.3 is not supported anymore.

You should either find JavaFX 2 alternative to XCalendarPicker like http://netbeans.dzone.com/articles/creating-datepicker-control
or download old JavaFX 1.3 library (which I don't advise unless you are doing app only for yourself).

Comment: i have one question: in swing i can use only JavaFx 2.0, but not 1.3?

Comment: you can use FX1.3, but it's no easy due to script nature of 1.3 (and that's one the reason of using pure Java in FX 2.0) -- for guidelines see http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/scripting/javafx/javafx_and_java/